# Iframe URL variable update with Current Date in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a webpage query which have multiple iframe content. on that Iframe URL there is a date which is variable, i required to update with current date automatically.Can you please let me know how to do this , i am not using php.
Code is is below:

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
1. frame 
<iframe src="http://example.com/gui/v3/admin/oss/date'2015-06-15'/" border="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>

2. frame
<iframe src="http://example1.com/gui/v3date'2015-06-15'/admin" border="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>

3. frame
<iframe src="http://example2.com/explorer/index.html#/resources/network.action_set?modified_on%3E%20date('2015-06-09')" border="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>
4. frame
<iframe src="http://example2.com/explorer/index.html#/resources/network.cell_set?modified_on%3E%20date('**2015-06-15**')" border="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>
5. 
<iframe src="http://example3.com/explorer/index.html#/resources/monitor.platform_alerts?form=%7B%date('2015-06-11')" border="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: all you need is jQuery and the .attr() method. Could also be done with basic JS. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

You can create your iframes dynamically, via Javascript. E.g:

```js
var d = new Date(),
    year = d.getFullYear(),
    month = d.getMonth() + 1,
    day = d.getDate(),
    today = year + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' + month : month) + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' + day : day);

document.body.innerHTML = ('<iframe src="http://example.com/gui/v3/admin/oss/date\'__DATE__\'/" border="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>' +
'<iframe src="http://10.65.152.4:5000/gui/v3/admin/oss/vmumuas3x/" border="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>' +
'<iframe src="http://example2.com/explorer/index.html#/resources/network.action_set?modified_on%3E%20date(\'__DATE__\')" border="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>' +
'<iframe src="http://example2.com/explorer/index.html#/resources/network.cell_set?modified_on%3E%20date(\'**__DATE__**\')" border="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>' +
'<iframe src="http://example3.com/explorer/index.html#/resources/monitor.platform_alerts?form=%7B%date(\'__DATE__\')" border="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>').replace(/__DATE__/g, today);
```

Comment: Thanks Buzinas, But script which you have given is not working. Can you please let me know the full tags, I am beginner in web page development.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not working can you please let me know the exact code.

Comment: @DHANANJAYCHAUBEY that's the exact code. As you can run the snippet and see that it's working.

Comment: @DHANANJAYCHAUBEY inside a `script` tag, e.g: `<html><head></head><body><script>THE CODE HERE</script></body></html>`